# Ruby: Matching Delimiters

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to write a regex pattern to look for a delimiter within a string such as this: `'//;\n1;2'` where the character `;` serves as the delimiter for the given string. I'm trying to solve a common coding kata problem, so I don't necessarily want an answer in code, but an idea as to how I can accomplish this with regex. This delimiter is subject to change and could be any character. Any ideas? Here's what I've written so far in my production file.

```
class StringCalculator
  def add(numbers)
    return 0 if numbers.empty?
    return nil if numbers.end_with?('\n')
    numbers.tr!('\n', ',')
    numbers.split(',').map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
  end
end
```

**Spec:**

```
context 'when passed different delimiters' do
  it 'should support semicolons' do
    expect(@calculator.add('//;\n1;2')).to eq(3)
  end

  it 'should support percents' do
    expect(@calculator.add('//%\n1%5')).to eq(6)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the code kata problem you are solving? What happens if your delimiter was a 1, and your input required you to add 1 and 2 to produce 3?

Comment: @MxyL http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/

Comment: Here's how to get your delimiter: "to change a delimiter, the beginning of the string will contain a separate line that looks like this:   “//[delimiter]\n[numbers…]”" From there, it's trivial.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense now that I read it. I didn't expect the `\n` to be significant to the problem.

Comment: I don't think I'm giving anything away by mentioning that you can get the beginning of a string, up to a delimiter `';'` with this regex: `'//;\n1;2'[/([^;]*);/, 1] => "//"`.

Comment: I'm terrible with regex, one of the reasons why I chose to do this kata. Can you explain that @CarySwoveland

Comment: Ugh.. I'm still stuck. It's just this one damn part. Could you explain that a little more in detail @jmromer

Comment: The method I've used is [String#\[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). The regex contains one capture group, `([^;]*)` (capture group #1). Whatever is captured is retrieved by the `1` following the regex. `[^;]*` matches zero or more characters other than `';'`. The capture group must be followed immediately by `';'`.  We could alternatively write the capture group `(.*?)`, meaning capture any number of any character, but (because it ends with `'?'`) do so "non-greedily", that is, up to the following `';'`. Without `'?'`, it would gobble up the entire line.

Comment: do you mean the code something like `str.split[str[2]] #=> ['//','\n1','5']`?

Comment: Well, @МалъСкрылевъ I ended up doing the simplest thing possible. ```numbers.slice(0, 2) == '//' ? ';' : ',' ```

Comment: @TheGrayFox what wish you get with the code, because `numbers.slice(0, 2) == '//' # => true`